# monotone likelihood ratio property of truncated distributions

Tags: statistics

What are the conditions that truncated normal distributions satisfy the monotone likelihood ratio property? How about other truncated distributions?

Comment: This seems like a rehash of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42488 (no answer accepted) and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36942 (no answer accepted) and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29391 by OP @Thales. None of the specific suggestions made in some of these about the MLR property and about the need to explain why one should care, what was tried by the OP, where the OP got stuck and the like, were acknowledged nor commented nor applied.